# Moodle and errors with file format

Tags: mysql, configuration, moodle

Recently I was trying to set up Moodle on my localhost and kept getting errors asking me to change two things.

1) change file format to Barracuda 
2) turn on innodb_large_prefix.

Being new to these things I didn't know where to start and I couldn't find any useful information to solve my problem (lack of skills on my part), so I thought I share how I fixed my problem.

You need to edit your MySQL my.ini file which should be within the xampp/mysql directory.

add these two lines to my.ini file and restart mysql and apache server:

`innodb_file_format=Barracuda
innodb_large_prefix=ON`

I hope this will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

When you setup 3.2+ or upgrade moodle from older version to 3.2+, MySQL need to support full unicode which means utf8mb4.

Below are the two links where steps has been clearly mentioned.
https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/MySQL

https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/MySQL_full_unicode_support

This is one nice article https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4